# OCR to MathJax utility

Tags: ocr

Is there utility that input an image of formula (commonly from e-book screen shot), then it output the MathJax code for it? With such utiliy asking physics/math questions will be easier if there is a lot of complex formula from book.

Better to be light weighted or even open source.

Comment: https://mathpix.com/ but this is not open source, sorry :/